# Vector of function with lambda functions

Tags: c++, function, vector

This code is not correct:

```
std::vector<int (*)(int)> fv;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
   auto g = [i](int n) -> int
   {
      return n+i;
   };

   fv.push_back(&g);
}
```

because lambda functions is not of type `int (*)(int)` but is an object.
My question is: what type I must put in `vector<...>`?

Comment: `function<int(int)>`, also don't store pointer to local variables, i.e. `fv.push_back(g);`

Comment: I don't know "function". Can you explain to me?

Comment: `std::function`, it is just wrapper for copyable objects.

Comment: As soon as you use captures your lambda does not match the simple function prototypes. It is best to think of it as a temporary class with an operator() and other members to handle the capture, and it might be implemented that way. `std::function` is a template that can represent any object with a `()` operation, including lambdas.

Comment: Thank you Gem Taylor for your explanation.

Comment: Thank you for trying the crazy thing of a vector of lambdas. I'm still not sure how I would use it in practice!

Comment: One can use it for composing functions.

 int compose(std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> fv, int init) {
  int x = init;
  for (auto& f : fv) {
    x = f(x);
  }
  return x;
}

If it is useful :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the library type [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

void foo() {
  std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> fv;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    fv.emplace_back([i](int n) {
      return n + i;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem with the original code is that the lambda does a capture (the index i).
without the capture the lambda would be convertible to the int(*)(int) pointer to function and the code would compile.

using a std::function works but it carries a performance penalty so the better question is what problem do you intend to solve with the vector of functors?

Comment: I want only to create a vector of functions to see if it was possible do it in c++.